# How do I modify the CSS for the 404 template in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I am a WordPress newbie - just launched my first site.  I am trying to modify the CSS for the 404 page.  Through FTP, I lave located the 404.php file.  However, I can not find the associated CSS.  I am having the same problem with the Search Results page.

I have been able to modify CSS on other pages by using Firebug, and then adding a CSS definition in Dashboard.  But, I want to just modify the file directly.

Could someone point me in the right direction here?  How do find the CSS for 404.php and the search results page?

Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: What you mean not finding css ?.! if you find out 404.php file then change class and add your own class. or from inspect element you can change css and add it on style.css

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143918/wordpress-404-page-shows-html-code/36146304#36146304

Comment: OK, I see.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If well configured, wordpress adds a `"error404"` class to `<body>`, therefore you can use something like:

```
.error404 p{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

to add styles to all "p" tags in the 404 page.

**If the required element already have related styles, try to add more parents to it in order not to have your styles overridden.**

```
.error404 .content-holder p{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

In addition, firebug can also help u identifying css files for each given style:

[image: Firebug]

just hover on the link next to the given attribute to find out which css file is affecting it.

Best of luck!

Comment: This is great advice.  Thank you!